# How to use deployment slots of app services with Github Source code

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am deploying my application from Github and I have three different deployment slot(Dev/Staging/prod) and would like to deploy the code only to Dev and swap the deployed code to the rest of the stages.

Just to not I don't have any pipeline tool yet so would like to understand with command line or GUI option as it is proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Azure CLI or powershell to access it.

[Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-cli-deploy-github):

```
# Replace the following URL with a public GitHub repo URL
gitrepo=https://github.com/Azure-Samples/php-docs-hello-world
webappname=mywebapp$RANDOM

# Deploy code from a public GitHub repository. 
az webapp deployment source config --name $webappname --resource-group myResourceGroup \
--repo-url $gitrepo --branch master --manual-integration
```

[Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-powershell-deploy-github):

```
# Replace the following URL with a public GitHub repo URL
$gitrepo="https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-dotnet-get-started.git"
$webappname="mywebapp$(Get-Random)"
$location="West Europe"

# Configure GitHub deployment from your GitHub repo and deploy once.
$PropertiesObject = @{
    repoUrl = "$gitrepo";
    branch = "master";
    isManualIntegration = "true";
}
Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols -ResourceName $webappname/web -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

After publishing it to azure, you could [swap the slot via the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#swap-deployment-slots), also the azure [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#automate-with-azure-powershell) and [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Thanks @joywang.  I use the above script which sets the Deployment slot to Prod environment . So any time I check in a code it will deploy to Prod .  I need a way to deploy the code to Dev slot  . I can do this in UI by removing the deployment slot from Prod and staging . Is there any way from CLI ? or I am not sure if it is a better way too .

Comment: @satish Just specify the `webappname` with your Dev slot name in the command, slot is like a copy with the web app, the command is also valid to deployment slot.